# remove backslash from string lua

Tags: string, lua

I working with some url string and i tried to remove "\" from the string to use url for my further use.
But when i tried using strin.gsub its not working as it should. rather then its giving me wrong output.

the String is

```
nas="\\192.168.1.220\STORAGE_1d1b7\a\b\c"
```

Code I have tried:

```
nas=string.gsub(nas,'\\',"")
print(nas)
```

Output:

```
192.168.1.220STORAGE_1d1b7??c
```

Output i need:

```
192.168.1.220STORAGE_1d1b7_a_b_c
```

its removing the "\" but it also affecting the "\" with "?"
i don't know where the "?" comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character `\` is used to escape some special characters in a string, for eg.: `\n` represents a newline character (ASCII code `10`) etc. (`\a` is ASCII code 7 in C/C++)

So, you'd need to define your string as:

```
nas = "\\\\192.168.1.220\\STORAGE_1d1b7\\a\\b\\c"
```

Alternatively, lua provides another way to define raw strings:

```
nas = [[\\192.168.1.220\STORAGE_1d1b7\a\b\c]]
```

Comment: ok using the raw format it elements the "?" but its also affect "\". i think i have to replace "\" with "_"  in one operation means when string.gsub removes the "\\" with "" it also replace the "\" with "_". how do i implement that?

Comment: So far removed the"\\" but still "\" giving me pain......                                                      'code' nas=[[\\192.168.1.220\STORAGE_1d1b7\a\b\c]]

i=string.find(nas,"\\",1)
nas=string.sub(nas,3)
nas=string.gsub(nas,"[['%\']]","_")
print(nas)

Comment: @user1640175 You need to escape `\ ` in the `string.gsub` function as well.

Comment: How do i do that? I have tried many patterns. but still the same. also i dont want to just remove it i want to replace the "\" with "_".

Comment: @user1640175 `nas = nas:gsub('\\\\', ''):gsub('\\', '_')`

Comment: ok, it worked for what i asked before but later on i found that when if i use STORAGE name after folder it want worked. so right now it if i use

Comment: ok, it worked for what i asked before but later on i found that when if i use STORAGE name after folder it want worked. so right now it if i use 'NASLocation = [[\\192.168.1.220\STORAGE_1d1b7\a\b\c]] NASLocation = NASLocation:gsub('\\\\', ''):gsub('\\', '_')' then it gives the output:'192.168.1.220_STORAGE_1d1b7_a_b_c' and that gives error. it worked if there is no under score after "STORAGE_1d1b7".so how can i make it to not apply under score after "STORAGE_1d1b7".

Answer (score 0):

Any ways Figured it out....

```
NASLocation = NASLocation:gsub('\\\\', ''):gsub('\\', '_',1):gsub('\\','/')
```